# Check if a string within an array contains another string React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

The code below is supposed to take in data from Firebase as an array and then filter it depending on if values include a string. An example of the data is seen below:

```
data = [
{
    "number": 1,
    "waterCapacity": 50,
    "diameter": 229,
    "workingPressure": 200,
    "testPressure": 300,
    "h2Compatible": "no",
    "designStandard": "ISO 9809-1",
    "approval": "TPED",
    "inletThread": "25E",
    "manufacturer": "Worthington",
    "specificationNumber": 19313614,
    "comments": "rev 16.09.2014",
    "country": "cylinder"
},
{
    "number": 2,
    "waterCapacity": 50,
    "diameter": 229,
    "workingPressure": 200,
    "testPressure": 300,
    "h2Compatible": "no",
    "designStandard": "ISO 9809-1",
    "approval": "TPED",
    "inletThread": "25E",
    "manufacturer": "Vitkovice",
    "specificationNumber": 19313601,
    "country": "cylinder"
}
]
```

My code for retrieving the data and filtering it can been seen below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Button,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import StickyHeaderFooterScrollView from 'react-native-sticky-header-footer-scroll-view'
import Statusbar from '/Users/paulg/Desktop/LindeProject/LindeProject/components/Statusbar.js'
import ViewContainer from '/Users/paulg/Desktop/LindeProject/LindeProject/components/ViewContainer.js'
import {styles} from '/Users/paulg/Desktop/LindeProject/LindeProject/authentication/styles.js'
import {firebaseRef} from '/Users/paulg/Desktop/LindeProject/LindeProject/services/Firebase.js'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import SearchCylinder from '/Users/paulg/Desktop/LindeProject/LindeProject/Pages/searchCylinder.js'
import {Table, Row, Rows} from 'react-native-table-component'

export default class valveDB extends Component{
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Cylinder Database',

  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
      this.state = {
        data: [],
        countryArray: '',
        region:'',
        countrySelected: ''
       }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

 fetchData = async () => {
   var data1 = [];
   let approval = this.props.navigation.state.params.approval
   let comments = this.props.navigation.state.params.comments
   let designStandard = this.props.navigation.state.params.designStandard
   let diameter = this.props.navigation.state.params.diameter
   let h2Compatible = this.props.navigation.state.params.h2compatible
   let inletThread = this.props.navigation.state.params.inletThread
   let manufacturer = this.props.navigation.state.params.manufacturer
   let specificationNumber = this.props.navigation.state.params.specificationNumber
   let testPressure = this.props.navigation.state.params.testPressure
   let waterCapacity = this.props.navigation.state.params.waterCapacity
   let workingPressure = this.props.navigation.state.params.workingPressure
   var fireBaseResponse = firebase.database().ref().orderByChild("country").equalTo("cylinder");
   fireBaseResponse.once('value').then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(item =>{
        const temp = item.val();
        data1.push(temp);
        return false;
    });
////////Filter Method/////////
      if(approval == '') {
        console.log("good")
      }
      else {
        data1 = data1.filter(x => x.approval.includes("TP"))
      }
      if(waterCapacity == '') {
        console.log("good")
      }
      else {
        data1 = data1.filter(x => x.waterCapacity == waterCapacity)
      }
      if(designStandard == '') {
        console.log("good")
      }
      else {
        data1 = data1.filter(x => x.designStandard == designStandard)
      }
      if(diameter == '') {
        console.log("good")
      }
      else {
        data1 = data1.filter(x => x.diameter == diameter)
      }
      if(inletThread == '') {
        console.log("good")
      }
      else {
        data1 = data1.filter(x => x.inletThread == inletThread)
      }
      if(workingPressure == '') {
        console.log("good")
      }
      else {
        data1 = data1.filter(x => x.workingPressure == workingPressure)
      }
      if(comments == '') {
        console.log("good")
      }
      else {
        data1 = data1.filter(x => x.comments == comments)
      }

      if(manufacturer == '') {
        console.log("good")
      }
      else {
        data1 = data1.filter(x => x.manufacturer == manufacturer)
      }
      if(testPressure == '') {
        console.log("good")
      }
      else {
        data1 = data1.filter(x => x.testPressure == testPressure)
      }

      if(specificationNumber == '') {
        console.log("good")
      }
      else {
        data1 = data1.filter(x => x.specificationNumber == specificationNumber)
      }
      if(h2Compatible == '') {
        console.log("good")
      }
      else {
        data1 = data1.filter(x => x.h2Compatible == h2Compatible)
      }


/////////////////////Filter Method////////////////// 
if(data1.length == 0){
  this.setState({countrySelected: "No Results Were Found"}) }
      data1 = data1.slice(0, 50);
      this.setState({data: data1});


    });
  }
  render(){
    var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    let {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
    return(
    <ViewContainer>
        <ScrollView maximumZoomScale = {5} scrollEnabled = {true} minimumZoomScale = {1} zoomScale = {.8}>
         <FlatList
                data = {this.state.data}
                keyExtractor = {(x, i) => i.toString()}
                renderItem ={({item}) =>
                    <Text style = {styles.itemText}>
                        Approval: {item.approval} | Manufacturer: {item.manufacturer} | Specification Number: {item.specificationNumber} |
                        H2 Compatible: {item.h2Compatible} | Diameter: {item.diameter} | Water Capacity: {item.waterCapacity} |
                        Inlet Thread: {item.inletThread}{"\n"}
                    </Text>
                }
            />
            <Text style = {styles.countryErrorText}>{this.state.countrySelected}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    </ViewContainer>

    )
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is when I try to do x.approval.includes("TP"). When I do that I get the warning message seen below:

[Warning Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnayO.png)

When I change it to lets say: x.approval == "TPED" it works fine so I am not exactly sure where to problem is.

I've been stuck on this for a few days so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `x.approval.contains("TP")`

Comment: I get a similar warning message when I do x.approval.conatins("TP")

Comment: That suggests that `x.approval` is no populated as expected.  Add `console.log(x)` so you can see the object in the console and check the values.

Comment: I just get the TypeError: x.approval.contains is not a function

Comment: You added the line `console.log(x);` and it gave you that error?  Nothing else changed?

Comment: I tried to do it with chrome debugging but the console was not working so I did it through Xcode and thats what it gave me.

Comment: You need to debug that object and check the properties.  You'll probably see your problem immediately when you do that.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry i am very new to React Native

Comment: I've already told you how to do it but your browser console apparently doesn't work.  I can't help you.

Comment: I am pressing cmd d and selecting debug js remotely but when I open up the chrome debugger and the console, nothing is logged.

Comment: I got chrome debugger to work. When I run what you told me I get nothing logged in the console and the warning message of a possible unhandles promise rejection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that it was searching for a property within the array object called includes. Obviously it could not find it so it was giving me the warning that the property did not exist. To fix this I changed the line to

```
let filteredData = data.filter(x => String(x.approval).includes(approvalVariable));
```

I hope this helps somebody else out in the future and you don't spend a week trying the figure it out with no help like I did.